# 1960s sci-fi anthology with a Viking fighting a U.S. army MP on the cover

Tags: story-identification, anthology-book

A sci-fi collection with a Viking and a U.S. army MP fighting each other on the cover. I lost this in 1967. It was a paperback anthology.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  This is really thin on details; can you recall anything about even 1 of the stories in the anthology?  Every bit of extra information helps.

Comment: That's it! lost it in 1967 and couldn't remember enough about the stories in it. I will be looking to get a copy of this ASAP!

Comment: User14111, Thank you very much. I will have a few more questions about stories I remember from the 60s. You have made this old man's day!!!

Answer (score 35, accepted):

[image]

This is the 1962 Ace paperback edition of a 1957 hardcover anthology, [*The Best from Fantasy and Science Fiction, Sixth Series*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?191001), edited by [Anthony Boucher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anthony_Boucher). The cover by [Ed Valigursky](http://www.pulpartists.com/Valigursky.html) is inspired by [Poul Anderson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poul_Anderson)'s story ["The Man Who Came Early"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Man_Who_Came_Early). Note the letters MP on the soldier's helmet.

Comment: How did you find that?

Comment: @GC_ :  Probably by having read "The Man Who Came Early" and then looking for anthologies with it and a cover that matches the description.  My first thought on reading the description of the cover was "Oh,  bet I know that story.  Don't know the anthology, but the picture sure sounds like 'The Man Who Came Early.'"

Comment: @GC_ I happen to have a copy of that book in my collection. Probably bought it new back in 1962.

Comment: Possible inspiration for Paul Gazis's NASA Ames Barbarian Affairs Office document ["Procedure to Follow in the Event That Building 245 is Attacked by Vikings"](http://paulgazis.com/Humor/Vikings.htm)?

Comment: User14111, I have ordered a copy from thriftbook. Thanks again!